# Parse ascii-art in R

Tags: r

I have some data that's generated by another program in basically an ASCII-art form.

```
 ----++++++++++++
 5555566667888889
 0246802468024680
 0000000000000000
 ................
 0000000000000001
 0000000000000020
 0000000000000300
```

The parsing of this data that makes sense is:

    `col1, col2
    -, 500.0
    -, 520.0
    -, 540.0
    -, 560.0
    +, 580.0
    +, 600.0
    +, 620.0
    +, 640.0
    +, 660.0
    +, 780.0
    +, 800.0
    +, 820.0
    +, 840.0
    +, 860.003
    +, 880.02
    +, 900.1`

Any tips on writing a parse for something this messy?

Answer (score 0):

If this is your data

```
tt <- "----++++++++++++
5555566667888889
0246802468024680
0000000000000000
................
0000000000000001
0000000000000020
0000000000000300"
```

The we can split into lines, and then split those lines by character and dump it into a matrix. We can then run functions over the matrix to get the values out you want.

```
lines <- strsplit(tt, "\n")[[1]]
cells <- t(do.call(rbind, strsplit(lines, "")))
signs <- cells[, 1]
digits <- apply(cells[, -1], 1, paste, collapse="")
data.frame(col1= signs, col2=as.numeric(digits))
```